# Application using bootstrap 3 and 4 together has conflicts

Tags: angularjs, angular, sass, ng-bootstrap, angular1.6

I have an App that uses bootstrap 3 and 4. Its a pretty massive application and built on combination of angular 1 and 2 and we already have a lot of scss files written for our angular 1 application.

I need to:

Make sure all the scss written until now doesnt affect our ng2-components that will be inserted into angular 1 pages.

Angular 4/bootstrap 4 scss should not affect current angular 1/ bootstrap 3

Currently for angular 1 we have main.scss file that imports all components styles :

```
.ng1-app, *:not(.ng2-app){

  @import "bootstrap3";

  //override vendor theme of slick-carousel
  @import "fonts/slick-font";
  @import "components/slick-carousel";

  // Variables & Mixin
  @import "helpers/variables";
  @import "helpers/mixin";
  @import "helpers/typography";

  //Fonts
  @import "fonts/icon-font";
  @import "fonts/font";
  @import "fonts/icon-font-2";

  //Layout
  @import "layout/common";
  @import "layout/header";
  @import "layout/main";
  @import "layout/sidebar";

 // Components
 @import "components/navbar";
 @import "components/tabs";
 @import "components/checkbox";

}
```

And for angular 2 we have a vendor.scss file to import bootstrap 4:

```
.ng2-app, *:not(.ng1-app) {
  @import '../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap4';
}
```

Quick example in html:

```
<div class="ng-one">
 <p class="test">This is ng1 test</p>
 <div class="ng-two">
  <p class="test">This is ng2 test</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Looking for direction since there are very little resources on building hybrid applications with angular1/2 and bootstrap 3/4.

Thanks

Comment: Taken from bootstrap: Bootstrap 4 is a major rewrite of almost the entire project. I'd recommend [migrating](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/) if possible.

Comment: That is why I wanted to confine bootstrap 3 only under a specific class thats written with angular 1 and rest use bootstrap 4. Doing a full migration to B4 is unfortunately not an option right now :(

Comment: Sounds like a migration nightmare but I'm pretty sure what you have is the best solution... perhaps the only solution.